# Calling Html.ActionLink in a custom HTML helper

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html-helper

I am designing a custom HTML helper and I would like to execute Html.ActionLink to provide dynamic URL generation.

```
    namespace MagieMVC.Helpers
    {
        public static class HtmlHelperExtension
        {
            public static string LinkTable(this HtmlHelper helper, List<Method> items)
            {
                string result = String.Empty;

                foreach (Method m in items)
                {
                    result += String.Format(
                        "<label class=\"label2\">{0}</label>" +
                        System.Web.Mvc.Html.ActionLink(...) +
                        "<br />",
                        m.Category.Name,m.ID, m.Name);
                }

                return result;
            }


  }
}
```

Unfortunately Html.ActionLink is not recognized in this context whatever the namespace I have tried to declare.

As a generic question, I would like to know if it is possible to use any existing standard/custom Html helper method when designing a new custom helper.

Thanks.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Don't you have the `helper` already?

```
helper.ActionLink("text", "actionName");
```

Don't forget to include `using System.Web.Mvc.Html` namespace.

And yes, you could use the existing extension methods as long as you included the necessary namespaces.

Answer (score 4):

FYI, for MVC 3, I found the ActionLink here:

```
System.Web.Mvc.Html.LinkExtensions.ActionLink(text, action, controller).ToHtmlString();
```

Comment: 1st parameter above must include reference to htmlhelper see below

Comment: public static MvcHtmlString ActionLinkCustom(this System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper html, string menutext, string action, string controller) .......
        string link = System.Web.Mvc.Html.LinkExtensions.ActionLink(html,menutext, action, controller).ToHtmlString();